# Error insert element (primary key)

Tags: java, web-services, jpa, playframework, playframework-1.x

I have one problem with my configuration of play framework, when I insert a new `Notification` I have received the error. I don´t know why this error occured. Because I extends `Model` class, Play must generated a new ID for each row.

If you can say to me what is the problem, or other better way to do this, Maybe if I extends the `GenericModel` and I do the code that is commented like this:

```
// @Id
// @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
// public long id;
```

but if I do this, How I must do the insert a new row?

Thanks a lot!!!!

---

Error found:

> **PersistenceException occured** : `org.hibernate.HibernateException`: The database returned no natively generated identity value

This is `/app/controllers/WSConfiguracion.java` :

```
if (cliente.valorBateria < filasConfiguracionClientes.get(i).limiteBateria) {   
    if (!estadoNotificacion.hayNotiBateria) {

       // code below generated the error
       Notificacion notificacion = new Notificacion(
          filasConfiguracionClientes.get(i).imeiadmin,imei, "bateria baja"
       ).save();

       estadoNotificacion.hayNotiBateria = true;
       //notificacion.save();
       estadoNotificacion.save();
       renderText("NOTIFICA BATERIA");
    }
} else {
    ...
}
```

#### This is my model.

```
package models;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import play.db.jpa.Model;

@Entity
public class Notificacion extends Model {
   //@Id
   //@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   //public long id;

   //@Id
   public long imeiadmin;
   //@Id
   public long imeiclient;
   public String detalleNotificacion;

   public Notificacion(long imeiadmin, long imeiclient,String detalleNotificacion) {
      this.imeiadmin = imeiadmin;
      this.imeiclient = imeiclient;
      this.detalleNotificacion = detalleNotificacion;
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you reformat that a little bit to make it readable? Remove the line numbers for example.

Answer (score 1):

I think the error:

> **PersistenceException occured** : `org.hibernate.HibernateException`: The database returned no natively generated identity value

is occurred because there is **no sequence** in your database. If you extends `Model` class for your model and you are on **Development** mode, Play!Framework automatically generated sequence on your database named `hibernate_sequence`. The sequence is used to generated **ID** for your model. You may check your database to ensure that sequence is present.

If the `hibernate_sequence` is present, you can insert data like you do before :

```
Notificacion notificacion = new Notificacion(
      filasConfiguracionClientes.get(i).imeiadmin,imei, "bateria baja"
).save();
```

then, the error above should be resolved.

---

> #### Note:
>
> > I am referring this answer if you used **PostgreSQL** database. If you use other database such as **MySQL**, you should define `AUTO_INCREMENT` on ID column as the sequence definition.

---

#### Update - I have tried this for H2 DB setting

Using `H2` database as configure in `application.conf` :

```
# Development mode
application.mode=dev
# Set simple file written database (H2 file stored)
db=fs
# JPA DDL update for development purpose only
jpa.ddl=update
```

#### The controller :

```
public static void test15878866() {
   // force to insert dummy data
   Notificacion notificacion = new Notificacion(
      1L, 2L, "This is new notificacion"
   ).save();

   renderText(notificacion.detalleNotificacion);
}
```

#### The model :

```
@Entity
public class Notificacion extends Model {
   public long imeiadmin;
   public long imeiclient;
   public String detalleNotificacion;

   public Notificacion(long imeiadmin, long imeiclient,String detalleNotificacion) {
      this.imeiadmin = imeiadmin;
      this.imeiclient = imeiclient;
      this.detalleNotificacion = detalleNotificacion;
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your answer, I´m using now the systme file server like a database and I´m using the development mode in the conf file, but the error don´t dissapear. I don´t know where I can enabled hibernate_sequence. I will do a MySQL database for production but for development I preffer file system for testing. When I will do a MySQL database, where I will have to define AUTO_INCREMENT? Thanks!!!

Comment: Are you use `SQLite` or `H2` database for development? I'm not familiar with `SQLite` but, if you use in-memory database like those and have extend your Model (`Notification.java`) with `Model` **not** `GenericModel`, the error should not appear. The sequence will be generated automatically. And then, for `MySQL` configuration for AUTO_INCREMENT you should follow this [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-using-sequences.htm). Hope it can help you.

Comment: Yes I use H2 database for development and I extend my `Model` `Notification.java` with Model and no other ID only the ID autogenerated but the error continue appearing. It´s strange. Thanks you very much for your time.

Comment: Ok, please. I don´t know why this error... Is very strange... Post your code and I´ll try now and I tell you the results. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please check the code that I have tried.. ;) When you call `test15878866()` action it should render the text, no error occured.. :)

Comment: This is crazy my friend. I have been trying all but the error persist. I have all like your example, I extends `Model`, I haven´t got any other ID in my model `Notificacion` and I have the same like you in my application.conf . This is very very strange, Do you know another form to do this?? Maybe extends the `GenericModel`? If you want I can show you my project in skype or similar. Thank you very much!

Comment: Okay, you can chat with me. Maybe we should use chat.stackoverflow.com to chat.. :) My internet connection is a bit poor if use skype.. :( You can contact me if I am online..

Comment: Hi!!! I have already resolved the problem!!! You won´t believe it!! I forgot to add super() at the first of the constructor... I add this and the problem is solved! Thank you very much for your help!! When you want I invite you a couple of beers!

Comment: Your pleasure, my friend.. :) I'm glad to know you have solved the problem. Okay, I think you should post your solution here, so other people may know. And I suggest you to add the error description on the question title.

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake!! I have only had to add **super();** inside the constructor.
Thanks for all, iwawiwi.

**The model :**

```
@Entity
public class Notificacion extends Model {
public long imeiadmin;
public long imeiclient;
public String detalleNotificacion;

  public Notificacion(long imeiadmin, long imeiclient,String detalleNotificacion) {
  super();
  this.imeiadmin = imeiadmin;
  this.imeiclient = imeiclient;
  this.detalleNotificacion = detalleNotificacion;
  }
}
```